# How to explode a string using preg_match_all

Tags: php

I have one flat file.I want to convert it into csv.
Flat file format is

```
"XXX" "H345" 2 "S" 1 "*" 0 01/03/2001 31/03/2002 "WORK IN PROGRESS" "" "" "" ""
```

Here fields are separated by space.

I follow the following steps to convert it

```
$file1="job.txt";
$file2="job.csv";
$content=file_get_contents($file1);
$arr=explode("\n",$content);
$f=fopen($file2,'w');   
foreach($arr as $value)
{
  $linearr=explode(' ',$value);
  fputcsv($f, $linearr);            

}
```

Here problem is its also explode the "WORK IN PROGRESS" into three different field.
How to solve this ?? If I used preg_match_all than how to make regular expression for this case ??

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your format is almost CSV, so you could use CSV functions such as [`str_getcsv`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php).

```
$string = '"XXX" "H345" 2 "S" 1 "*" 0 01/03/2001 31/03/2002 "WORK IN PROGRESS" "" "" "" ""';
                          // v -- there is space
print_r(str_getcsv($string, ' ')); // < -- you should use it
                          // ^ -- it's your custom delimiter
//Array
//(
//    [0] => XXX
//    [1] => H345
//    [2] => 2
//    [3] => S
//    [4] => 1
//    [5] => *
//    [6] => 0
//    [7] => 01/03/2001
//    [8] => 31/03/2002
//    [9] => WORK IN PROGRESS
//    [10] => 
//    [11] => 
//    [12] => 
//    [13] => 
//)
```

or [fgetcsv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)

Comment: I tried this using $a=str_getcsv($value);fputcsv($f, $a); But here put the one line in one cell

Comment: @user3675101, Have you read my example carefully? Have you seen last argument of `str_getcsv`?